# how to get Hex code from RGB value using objective c

Tags: objective-c

Could any one help me how to convert the RGB value to Hex code through iphone application?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many bits per color?

Answer (score 6):

Following @Олег Трахман's answer...

```
UIColor* myColor  = [UIColor brownColor];
const CGFloat* components;
components = CGColorGetComponents(myColor.CGColor);
NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", components[0],components[1],components[2],components[3]);
NSLog(@"%X, %X, %X, %X", (char)(255*components[0]), (char)(255*components[1]), (char)(255*components[2]), (char)(255*components[3]));
int hexValue = 0xFF0000*components[0] + 0xFF00*components[1] + 0xFF*components[2];  // for RGB
```

Should output:

```
0.600000, 0.400000, 0.200000, 1.000000
99, 66, 33, FF
```

And give you the actual Hex.

Comment: You might want to change the second NSLog to NSLog(@"%02X, %02X, %02X, %02X", (unsigned char)(255*components[0]), (unsigned char)(255*components[1]), (unsigned char)(255*components[2]), (unsigned char)(255*components[3])); or you will end up with unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIColor* myColor  = [UIColor brownColor];
CGFloat* components;
components = CGColorGetComponents(myColor.CGColor);
NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", components[0],components[1],components[2],components[3]);
```

=> 0.600000, 0.400000, 0.200000, 1.000000